# Draw a grid dynamically xaml c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview, grid

I want a grid in xaml tha can show me a collection of objects how should i proceed ?

I already binded these :

```
C# // Collection.DataContext = Mycollection;

xaml // Grid.RowSpan="{Binding getSizeofcollection}"
```

My collection contains all the same kind of object.
I want to show 1 object/row

Is that possible to create a template of how to show an object in a row then use it in the grid ?

Thanks for your advices

Edit :
In fact i can't bind to hashtables, but i can bind to a List
that's the source of my problems. Now i'm currently trying to transform my hashtable in a List

Edit n°2 : Ok i convert hashtable to a list correctly, but this xamlparse Exception is still here

Comment: Are you looking to simply create a single horizontal list of items? You might want to consider using an [ItemsControl](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/) if that's the case, and simply setting the `ItemsPanelTemplate` to a `StackPanel` with `Orientation=Horizontal`

Comment: I have a List of the same objects and i want each objects and their properties in a line of the DataGrid/StackPanel or something
So, 20 objects, 20 lines, A collumn for each property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Grid` is a layout container, not a control. You want to use a `DataGrid`, which will allow you to set the `ItemsSource` to your `Mycollection`. You can then either let it create the columns for you, or you take control and specifically define what columns you want and how they should be shown.

Comment: What's the difference with the Stackpanel ?

Comment: StackPanel is also a layout container. By 'layout container' I mean they are derived from 'panel' - which are used for layout. They don't implicitly hold/display your data themselves.

Comment: By the way i get a "xaml parse exception" when i set the item source like that
:
    collentionGrid.ItemsSource = mycollection.CollectionAll;

Comment: Sorry just noticed you were setting the DataContext to your collection. I tend to work with the MVVM pattern, so would set the data context of the view to a view model ... and within that view model I would have a property that was my collection. And that collection would then be bound to the ItemsSource of a DataGrid on that view.

Comment: awww, My collection contains 3 Hashtables and you can't bind these to datagrid soo... it's a bit getting complicated

Comment: You can bind them, but it is getting complicated and you'll end up having to change templates. Try just binding one of those hashtables to a datagrid to get the hang of what you're doing, then worry about your more complicated collection.

Comment: Post your exception - you can bind to a HashTable, so if you're getting the same error when converting to a List it should show that the problem isn't with the source of the binding but with something else.

Comment: In fact i misstyped itemsource so the datagrid didn't show anything
thanks for the answer
now it's solved and i undertand better the datacontext use

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, I'm finding your question is a bit unclear as to what you're asking for.

Based on your comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081041/draw-a-grid-dynamically-xaml-c-sharp/23088153#comment35287538_23081041)

> I have a List of the same objects and i want each objects and their properties in a line of the DataGrid/StackPanel or something So, 20 objects, 20 lines, A collumn for each property

It sounds like you just want a DataGrid.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Collection" ItemsSource="{Binding }" />
```

The default behavior of a `DataGrid` is to create a Row for each item, and to auto-generate a column for each property of the item. So if you have 20 objects of type `MyClass` in a list, and each contained 3 properties, it would auto-generate a grid with 20 rows and 3 columns.

However if I have misunderstood you and you're actually looking to create a horizontal StackPanel containing all your items in a line, and you don't need the selection/sorting capabilities that a DataGrid provides, I'd recommend using an [ItemsControl](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/) instead.

This is simply a control that will iterate over a collection, and draw each item in the collection with whatever template you specify. All the items get wrapped in a `<ContentPresenter>` and placed in whatever layout container you specify (default is a vertical StackPanel).

Since you said you want all items in a horizontal line, the best `ItemsPanelTemplate` would probably be a `StackPanel` with it's orientation set to `Horizontal`.

Your XAML would end up looking like this:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Collection" ItemsSource="{Binding }">
    <!-- ItemsPanelTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <!-- ItemTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- // put whatever XAML you want to use to draw each item here -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and Sorry for being unclear, i'll reformulate here :
In my main window, i create an instance of a class that contains collections
I add items to the collections and i want to show one of the collection in a datagrid in the main window.
each item of the collection in a row, with his properties as collumn.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some custom AttachedProperty.

Something like this:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1"
              commonUI:GridExtension.ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}"
              commonUI:GridExtension.Rows="{Binding RowDefinitions}"
              commonUI:GridExtension.Columns="{Binding ColumnDefinitions}"/>
```

For the documentation: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

But in your case, a simple ListBox or ItemsControl seem to be more appropriate...